# Get results from second table joined even if the initial select fails and vice versa

Tags: mysql, left-join, right-join

I am using the SELECT statement below to join the property table with the epc table. Not always is the EPC available for a property. I also want the epc table if the property does not exist.

```
SELECT p.dateAdded, p.paon, p.saon, p.street, p.locality, p.townCity, p.district, p.county, p.propertyType, 
     p.propertyType, p.oldNew, p.postcode, p.tenure, p.ppd, p.bedrooms, p.bathrooms, p.receptions, p.lastSalePrice, p.lastTransferDate, 
     e.INSPECTION_DATE, e.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA, e.CURRENT_ENERGY_RATING, e.POTENTIAL_ENERGY_RATING, e.CURRENT_ENERGY_EFFICIENCY, e.POTENTIAL_ENERGY_EFFICIENCY, 
     e.PROPERTY_TYPE 
      FROM property p
      LEFT JOIN epc e ON p.postcode = e.POSTCODE AND CONCAT(p.paon, ', ', p.street) = e.ADDRESS1 
      WHERE p.paon = 8 AND p.postcode = "TS6 9LN" 
      ORDER BY e.INSPECTION_DATE, p.lastTransferDate DESC 
      LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible to select both tables but if 1 doesn't exist, select the 1 that does?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Unfortunately MySQL does not implement this part of the SQL standard. You can simulate a full outer join with two outer joins, though, but it becomes long, and possibly quite cumbersome and error prone.

For example:

```
select a.col1, b.col2
from table_a a
LEFT join table_b b on ...
union -- here we union both outer joins
select a.col1, b.col2
from table_a a
RIGHT join table_b b on ...
```

In the second `SELECT` the table roles are inverted, since it uses a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.